# Ruby On Rails - NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

I'm trying to run on a new computer some ruby code and I receive the following error (rails db:migrate --trace)

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/Users/jairochavez/Documents/Rails/rfdf_bolivia/config/initializers/stripe.rb:2:in `<main>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
/Users/jairochavez/Documents/Rails/rfdf_bolivia/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:238:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:238:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/Documents/Rails/rfdf_bolivia/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/jairochavez/Documents/Rails/rfdf_bolivia/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
```

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = { 
  publishable_key: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:public_key], 
  secret_key:      Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:secret_key] 
} 
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Comment: Your `config/initializers/stripe.rb` is trying to call `:[]` on a `nil`. Perhaps show the content of that file?

Comment: Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:public_key],
  secret_key: Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:secret_key]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

Comment: Did you set all those `Rails.application.credentials` on your new machine? BTW, it is usually best to add code to your question rather than posting in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stacktrace you posted, this line in particular appears to be the issue:

```rb
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:public_key]
```

Since you're chaining multiple hash accesses, one of those objects is `nil`. You could try inspecting each of them by adding something like this to the top of the initializer:

```rb
puts Rails.application.credentials.inspect
puts Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym].inspect
puts Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe].inspect
```

That will tell you which part is `nil` that shouldn't be, and you can update your credentials file accordingly.

Comment: Good answer, and this is how I realized why it's nil. It was just nil during compilation. Weird how credentials are loaded to compile assets. Issue is closed, but really weird they closed it. Does not make any sense at all. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947

Answer (score 1):

Based on your configuration you should have your `credentials.yml` looking something like this:

```
stripe:
  secret_key: pk_123456789012345
  public_key: sk_abcdefghijklnmk
```

**In your stripe.rb you missed `[:secret_key]`. It should look like this. But this won't work either when you are precompiling in production.**

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:secret_key]
```

**Use dig method instead.**

So for your stripe.rb

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :secret_key)
```

In your terminal run

`RAILS_ENV=production rails c`

In the console run

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :secret_key)
```

Now you should get a value.

This was an issue I ran into and suffered until I figure it out. It seems to be an issue with rails code base. Not sure we need to load credentials to compile assets. Anyways, they close this issue but I am not sure why they closed it. Here is the link to the issue. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947

Answer (score 1):

config/initializer/stripe.rb

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(Rails.env.to_sym, :stripe, :secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

When cloning an existing repo, you might run into this error if you do not have a `config/master.key` file, (which is not checked in to source control, e.g. GitHub). This is because, as @Elias Glyptis pointed out, credentials are needed to compile assets, (as documented in [Rails #32947](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947)).